# LUA After adding names from _ENV into a table, how do I print the VALUE from the name and not just the "name"

Tags: variables, lua, environment-variables, quotes

```lua
    X=123
    Y=321
    TAB1={}
    z=1
    for n in pairs(_ENV) do
        TAB1[z] = n
        z=z+1
    end

-- did some more steps that removes general _ENV and only left with my script global variables

    TAB2={x, y} 
    print(TAB2[1])
```

what I want is "123" but I'm getting "x"

I've tried gmatch, gsub, tostring, but I still can't get it to print the value of x (123).  it's only printing "x"

**sorry I don't know how to work this text box correctly for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ive tried gmatch, gsub, tostring, but I still can't get it to print the value of x (123). it's only printing "x"

These functions are for string manipulation so I don't see how they'd be useful here. The reason for the lack of "value" is that your loop is `for n in pairs(_ENV) do`. [`pairs`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pairs) is just a wrapper for `next` which returns `key` and `value`, but you're currently discarding the value. Simply add a second variable to the for name list: `for name, value in pairs(_ENV) do print(value) end`. Alternatively, index `_ENV` using `n`: `print(_ENV[n])` (inside the loop).

Comment: thank you.  this seems to be working,  I'm getting a lot more of the unneeded data,  but I can work out a way to get just what I need.  thank you so much!!

Comment: oh this is perfect.  I placed "name" in TABLE1 and placed "value" in TABLE2. then exluded the unneeded data so only my variables remained. and now i can get name and value anytime i need it ! thank you so much!!!!